# Pandas multiple "group by" and compare values in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:

```
In:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [23, 23, 23, 43, 43],
               'data_1': ['20170503', '20170503', '20170503', '20170602',                   
               '20170602'],
               'units' : [10,10,10,5,5],
               'data_2' : ['20170104', '20170503', '20170503', '20170605', 
               '20170602'],
               'code': ["s", "r", "s", "s", "r"],
               'units_2': [20,10, 10, 8, 5 ]})

print(df)
```

Out:

```
   id    data_1     units    data_2    code  units_2
0  23  20170503     10     20170104       s       20
1  23  20170503     10     20170503       r       10
2  23  20170503     10     20170503       s       10
3  43  20170602      5     20170605       s        8
4  43  20170602      5     20170602       r        5
```

I need to groupby by "id" and check if there are dates in date_2 and "s" corresponding to date_1. One additional column can be added to tick those matches, so the final output will look like that:

```
   id    data_1     units    data_2    code  units_2     new_column
0  23  20170503     10     20170104       s       20              0
1  23  20170503     10     20170503       r       10              0
2  23  20170503     10     20170503       s       10              1
3  43  20170602      5     20170605       s        8              0
4  43  20170602      5     20170602       r        5              0
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `groupby` is not necessary, because values are not changed or count per groups.

Use:

```
df['new_column']=(df.data_1.eq(df.data_2)&df.code.eq('s')).astype(int)
# or df['new_column']=(df.data_1.eq(df.data_2)&df.code.eq('s')).map({True:1,False:0})
# or df['new_column'] = np.where((df.data_1.eq(df.data_2)&df.code.eq('s')),1,0)
print(df)

   id    data_1  units    data_2 code  units_2  new_column
0  23  20170503     10  20170104    s       20           0
1  23  20170503     10  20170503    r       10           0
2  23  20170503     10  20170503    s       10           1
3  43  20170602      5  20170605    s        8           0
4  43  20170602      5  20170602    r        5           0
```

Comment: I thought groupby was needed to compare data withing the same id.

Comment: anky_91,thank you very much. It works and very helpful!. I just thought some steps ahead but in fact, all that I need for this step is solved with your solution :)